# How give submit on selecting drop down in moqui Framework?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, moqui

I've implemented an application using Moqui Framework.I have form-single like this

```
 <transition name="languagesUptade">
  <service-call name="org.moqui.impl.UserServices.update#searchLanguage"
            in-map="[locale:locale]"/>
    <default-response url="."/></transition>

            <form-single name="languageslist" map="languages" transition="languagesUptade">

                <field name="locale" columnSize="col-sm-12"><default-field>
                    <drop-down allow-empty="false"><list-options list="localeStringList" key="${locale}" text="${locale} - ${name}"/></drop-down>
                </default-field></field>

                <field name="submitButton" columnSize="col-sm-12"><default-field title="Update"><submit/></default-field></field>
            </form-single>
```

I am trying to remove field submit-button and i need get submitted on selecting drop down and it need to call the transition. How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Write some JavaScript to do it, and put it in a render-mode.text element. There is an example of this in the QuickSearch screen in HiveMind:

https://github.com/moqui/HiveMind/blob/master/screen/HiveMindRoot/dashboard/QuickSearch.xml